# Check each number python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file and check to see that every number is present, all unique.  I tried checking the equality of the length of the list and the length of the set.  I get this error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  Do i have to convert the list to something else?

Here is code

```
def readMatrix(filNam):
    matrixList = []
    numFile = open(filNam, "r")
    lines = numFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()
        row = []
        for i in line:
            row.append(int(i))
        matrixList.append(row)
    return matrixList

def eachNumPresent(matrix):
    if len(matrix) == len(set(matrix)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: can you paste your exact stacktrace? Your stacktrace does not necessarily correspond to the code you have shown

Comment: Do not write `if foo: return True; else: return False`; write just `return foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"set" doesn't work on list of lists but works fine on list of tuples. So use the below code :

```
matrixList.append(tuple(row))
```

instead of :

```
matrixList.append(row)
```

Comment: thanks! that fixed the problem, but i was wondering how could i check equality of these three things should i convert the last one to look like the first two?  [65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
[65, 65, 65, 65, 65]
(65, 65)

Comment: You can't compare a list with a tuple, they are of different type. You have to have them in same type, either list or tuple, for comparison.

Comment: I converted them all to tuple but the last one only has two elements so it doesnt compare the three to true. I want it to be true if all the numbers are the same even if the last one has two elements

Comment: Use matrixList.append(tuple(set(row))) instead of matrixList.append(row). It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A list cannot be an element of a set, so you cannot pass a list of lists to set(). You need to unravel the list of lists to a single list, then pass to set (so integers are your set elements).

```
unraveled = [x for line in matrix for x in line]
return len(unraveled) == len(set(unraveled))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `matrix` is a list of lists. When you write `set(matrix)`, Python tries to create a set of all rows of the matrix. Your rows are lists, which are mutable and unhashable.

What you want is a set of all *values* in the matrix. You can count it with an explicit loop:

```
all_values = set()
for row in matrix:
  all_values.update(row)
# here all_values contains all distinct values form matrix
```

You could also write a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
all_values = set(x for row in matrix for x in row)
```